# What sends a PUT to a Spring controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

I want to send an email using ajax and PUT method to the controller. Well, I noticed that data is not being sent as a 'query parameter', but as 'form data'(https://zapodaj.net/f1b8ed0b2a16b.png.html). By what I can not use RequestParam. I need to apply RequestBody (I think). I created this dto

```
public class ChangeEmailDTO {
     @Getter @Setter private String email;
}
```

And the controller I modified in this way

```
 @PutMapping("/changeEmail")
public boolean changeEmail(
        @ReuqestBody ChangeEmailDTO changeEmailDTO
) {
    System.out.println("email: " + changeEmailDTO.getEmail());

    return true;
}
```

And shipping

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: '/changeEmail',
    data: {
        email: $('#email').val()
    },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('function');
    }
});
```

However, it does not work. I have no idea how to fix this. Maybe I need to use another annotation? The controller indicates there is no such address.

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? The DTO is null?

Comment: You need to register the `HttpPutFormContentFilter` to be able to do binding.

Comment: I using Spring Boot. After addressing the address, it throws me the default page(ErrorController) of the wrong address.